# Problem when running .ps1 script from external program

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to run simple Powershell script (eg. just with dir command) on Windows Server 2008 using external program which will call Powershell

```
powershell.exe "& 'C:\Temp\myscript.ps1'"
```

I have set (run as administrator) execution-policy unrestricted. After all, I get this error from the client

```
99: File C:\Temp\myscript.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please
 see "get-help about_signing" for more detai  ls.  At line:1 char:2  + & <<<<  'C:\Temp\myscript.ps1'      + CategoryInfo
: NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Why I'm getting this error? Isn't unrestricted execution policy enough?

Comment: Problem solved: There is two Powershell's in Windows Server 2008, x64 and x86. I had to set execution policy unrestricted in both of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or

You can use -ExecutionPolicy parameter of PowerShell.exe to set the execution policy to unrestricted only for that session. This helps in keeping the system wide policy to deafult.